# Is randomsound for increasing entropy pool not doing what it is supposed to do?

Tags: random-number-generator, entropy, cryptographic-hardware

I am using randomsound because I thought it would be a good idea to inject some additional entropy into the entropy pools of my linux machines (clearly those machines have a corresponding sound card).

(Un)fortunately, I am a quite paranoid person, and, therefore, I am reviewing the source of [randomsound](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/randomsound/0.2-5) in the moment and got stuck at the following code pieces:

In randomsound.c, there is the structure

```
struct injector {
  int ent_count;
  int size;
  union {
    int ints[128];
    BitField bitfield[512];
  } value;
} random_injector;
```

which is used to transfer the noise from the sound card to `/dev/random`

```
if (ioctl(randomfd, RNDADDENTROPY, &random_injector) == -1) {
  perror("ioctl");
}
```

However, it is said explicitly (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118705/using-rndaddentropy-to-add-entropy-to-dev-random) that *injector* must match random.h's struct rand_pool_info.

This struct is filled with data via

```
for (i = 0; i < depositsize; ++i) {
  bitbuffer_extract_bits(buffered_bits, random_injector.value.bitfield + i, 8);
}
```

which obviously only works on *injector's* BitField.

So the actual problem is this *ints*-array in *injector*, which is always of size 128 int and is never used in the code. The default size of `depositesize` is 64. And as far as I can tell, with this configuration, the entropy pool is increased by 64*8 bit and 64 bytes are written to the entropy pool. But those bytes belong to `int`s which is never touched.

So my main question is: Is the default configuration of randomsound always injecting the same bytes to the entropy pool? Or am I simply wrong with my interpretation of the code.

Answer (score 4):

Ah ... I see. I am not a C/C++-expert.

So the union in *injector* "projects"*ints* on *bitfield* and vice versa. That is, the start of *ints* and *bitfield* in memory is the same. Writing on *bitfield* automatically writes on *ints*.

See http://www.wachtler.de/ck/8_7_struct_union.html (in german).

So everything is fine.